# Maven how to interpolate a String inside a custom plugin

Tags: maven, plugins

I have a plugin that transforms a markdown file to other formats (xml, odt, pdf, html).

The project is not a code project, there is no Java in, no resources, and it does not produce classes nor jar files.

My source tree is :

```
src
 + main
   + exercices
      + book.md
      + images
        + ...
```

The markdown file may contains some project properties, as `${project.version}`.
I want to have the `book.md` being filtered - i.e. `${project.version}` replaced by the value in `pom.xml` - **without** creating a new file. I need the filtered content in a variable in the plugin

Something like :

```
String originalFileContent = readFileContent(inputFile);

String filteredFileContent = filterString(
   originalFileContent,
   project,
   session,
   customProperties);
```

My question is how to write this `filterString` method ...
I've look inside maven-resources-plugin source code, but it's not quite clear... it seems that it's only possible to filter resources, not strings...

**I do not want to filter a source file, nor produce a new file**, I just want to get the result into a variable.

Thanks in advance,
Christophe

Comment: You should reconsider to make those parts parameters of your plugin and those will be filtered automatically.. Also the question it looks a bit like log information... can you give more context and best would be some code how your plugin looks like etc.

Comment: I have edited the question, to make it clearer...